# Asp.net Core 2.2 Store entire DB table in memory EF Core

Tags: sql-server, azure, asp.net-core, memorycache, ef-core-2.2

I have a asp.net core 2.2 app hosted as an azure app service. This sporadically receives large amounts of burst traffic. Much of the resources go to verifying postal/zip codes. The queries to the postal code table are all selects. There are no updates or inserts. These queries are a performance bottleneck. The table itself is about 700mb. I've been looking for a way to store this particular table in memory at startup possibly as a separate db context. Is it possible to fill this secondary db context with data from a main context connected to the SQL DB at startup? Is this a bad idea?

Answer (score 1):

Putting them in memory is not a good idea. You might already be using shared resources in azure so this will impact the performance. Not sure about your limitations but i can suggest the following.

**Scale Up**

if you can try to scale up the db instance. Will certainly help.

**Query Optimization**

Work on query optimization if you haven't already. Look for best practices around.

**Read Replica**

If your table is part of transnational database you may create read-replica. Read replicas are optimized for read queries.

**Cache**

You can consider distributed cache like Redis. Depending on your table e.g. if it's look up data then let it build on demand using cache-aside pattern.

**NoSQL/Data ware house**

Performance of RDBMS is subjected to many factors. Accessing Data this big within transnational database will remain a challenge. If your business case allows , you can use NoSQL data store or dataware house solution.